# Global TypeScript installation without admin rights?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have Visual Studio 2017 projects that use TypeScript. 
The installed TypeScript versions are 2.3 and 2.5. 
On the windows machine, I have no admin rights.

The problem now is version 2.5 causes conflicts (due to TS bugs) with a newer version of TypeScript used by JetBrains Rider.

I'd like to install TypeScript 3.1.3 from the zip-file on github. 
But I can't get the admin to install it (or anything), because he's to lazy.

I see that all the installer does is unpacking files from the zip-file to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\<TS_VERSION>
```

But I don't have write access to this path, and I don't see this path configured anywhere in Visual Studio, or in the PATH environment variable, so I don't know where to override.

Is there any way to override/set the TypeScript SDK path in Visual Studio (without modifying the project file) ?